# Missing modules when using Pyinstaller to compile to exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyinstaller, qgis

My script runs fine but when I try to compile it via Pyinstaller, I get a 'Failed to execute script error in a message box'. Pyinstaller completes and creates a .exe but as soon as I open it I get the error. I also see in the warn log that I have missing modules. Below are the following modules I'm trying to import.

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import time, datetime
```

I don't really understand how the whole process works. I thought I would just provide pyinstaller with my script and it would compile. I've been reading about .spec files, hidden imports and wheels.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas? This is the command I've been running to compile the script.

```
C:\fran\files\gis\pyqt4_scripts\ C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed myscript.py
```

I've also tried with --onedir instead. All of the modules are found in my installation of python at C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages

**edit 11/5/2016 Is there a way I can explicitly tell pyinstaller where to find these files? Or explicitly import then somehow in my python script?

Comment: Can you rerun `pyinstaller` without the `--windowed` option, run from command line and post the error?

Comment: I ran without the --windowed option but when I ran the .exe, a black window appeared for a second then closed. I got the following while it was compiling in the command line 'WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lower cases : PyQt4.QtGui' I got the same warning but for PyQt4.QtCore. I think this is causing the problems. I have a ton of missing modules in the warn log also.

Comment: As I said, you have to run the exe from the command line. If you just double click it, the window closes and you can't see the error messages. The real culprit will show up there. Most of the times, the `pyinstaller` warnings don't result in errors.